# Are Monocle's Optionals the same as partial Lenses?

Tags: scala, lenses, monocle-scala

Monocle's optionals have the following access functions (for `Optional[C,A]`):

```
getOption: C => Option[A]
set: A => C => C
```

This is at odds with the original definition of (partial) asymmetric data lenses.  I would expect:

```
getOption: C => Option[A]
setOption: A => C => Option[C]
```

What is the reason for that?  How do I obtain classic partial lenses with Monocle?  When programming lenses I found that it much more problematic to ensure totality of set than of get ...

Comment: Monocle provides a `setOption` method on `Optional` that provides the operation you're looking for. `set` just returns the given `C` unmodified if there's no match.

Comment: So is the optional setter derivable from an optional getter and a total setter?

Comment: After inspecting the source code for `setOption`, it seems to me that it can never produce `None` so making a partial lense this way does not seem viable, does it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the following partial lens for looking up values in a list by index (note that this is just a pedagogical example, since `monocle.std.list.listIndex` provides this functionality off the shelf):

```
import monocle.Optional

def listIndexOptional[A](i: Int): Optional[List[A], A] =
  Optional[List[A], A](_.lift(i))(a => l =>
    if (l.isDefinedAt(i)) l.updated(i, a) else l
  )
```

Now we can define an `Optional` that points to the third item in a list of strings:

```
val thirdString = listIndexOptional[String](2)
```

And use it like this:

```
scala> thirdString.set("0")(List("a", "b", "c"))
res4: List[String] = List(a, b, 0)

scala> thirdString.set("0")(List("a", "b"))
res5: List[String] = List(a, b)
```

Note that if there is no third item, the operation just returns the list unmodified. If we wanted to know whether the item had been updated, we can use `setOption`:

```
scala> thirdString.setOption("0")(List("a", "b", "c"))
res6: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(a, b, 0))

scala> thirdString.setOption("0")(List("a", "b"))
res7: Option[List[String]] = None
```

The fact that the `Optional.apply` method takes as its second argument a function `A => S => S` is partly a convenience, since we often want to define partial lenses in this way, and partly so that we can't define a partial lens where `getOption` and `setOption` disagree on whether the target exists.

If you really want to, you can always define an `Optional` in terms of a `A => S => Option[S]` setter by tacking a `getOrElse(s)` on the end.

Comment: Another reason why (`getOption`, `set`) was selected as canonical definition of `Optional` is the diamond relationship between `Iso`, `Prism`, `Lens` and `Optional`. @puffnfresh made a nice [diagram](https://twitter.com/puffnfresh/status/654862731548446720) to show this.

Comment: Thanks! I understand. I misunderstood the implementation of setOption. I can see now that it uses modify and getOption, so it has all it needs to discover whether merging has succeded and failed.  I think I can work with this :)